# What does てよりかか mean? Found in the Shinmeikai dictionary

Tags: orthography, dictionary, punctuation

The Shinmeikai dictinary defines 椅子 as:

腰を掛け（てよりかか）るための家具

What does てよりかか mean there?

Comment: Inside the parentheses is not an independent chunk of words. It's meant to be parsed either including the parenthetical portion or not.

Comment: btw do you mean Shinmeikai? Because Shinnenkai means the new year's party.

Comment: Lol, yeah. I'll change it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

腰を掛ける (here in て-form) means *to sit* and 寄りかかる means *to lean on*.

A chair is a tool where you sit and rest your back against the back of the chair.

Comment: I see. So, I was parsing the full てよりかか when the て was there just to complete 腰を掛け- and then add よりかか (寄りかかる) to the definition. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nothing much to add to @永劫回帰's answer itself, just a follow-up about the format:

> 腰を掛け（てよりかか）るための家具

It's almost like writing in English:

> a piece of furniture for sitt(ing and reclin)ing on

Of course you usually don't want to write such a Frankenstein sentence in English, but Japanese has no spaces between words and can be broken anywhere, so why not? As a result, we don't hesitate to insert fragments in parentheses wherever both ends meet around them.

> 小さ（くて見づら）い字
> ブザーが聞こえ（なかっ）た時
> 無（理のない）課金

Comment: Is this at all common, though? If a native encountered this, would they consider it intelligible but highly unusual?

Comment: @jogloran A dictionary proudly makes use of it, no? ;-) (Well, my last example is obviously a joke meme, though.)